# Is it possible to disable Virtual Clone Drive from running on startup?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have Virtual Clone drive installed on Windows 7, but I only use it rarely. I would like to disable it from running on startup. I already checked the startup folder and msconfig, but I couldn't find a way to disable this service.

Comment: It appears in MSCONFIG on my system under the Startup tab. It's located in the Run key in the WOW64 node. "WhatInStartup" is a handy way to easily disable & re-enable programs and services.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[See this page](http://forum.slysoft.com/showthread.php?p=296374)

> You can set it in VCD prefs.
>   It will not start, if you disable the tray icon and set the number of virtual drives to 0 (disabled).

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Hit Windows+R (run). 
In the box that apears type msconfig. This will bring you to the system configuration.
Go to the tab that says windows start (or something like that, my sistem is not in english).
Find the entry that says virtual Clone Drive and uncheck it.
It will prompt you to restart, you may choose to do so later it doesn't matter.

Note: I would not recommend changing the registry unless you really know what you are doing, and even then, create a restore point before you do.

Cheers!